# How to view my Express app with fixed IP in browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-lightsail

I just create a NODE APP with express (Basic express generator in Apache server) in AWS Lightsail, I have a fixed IP http://44.197.139.141/, the app is installed in /mailing/ with default template from express, so the url is http://44.197.139.141/mailing, if you check url you get the files. I can't figure it out how to see my app, http://44.197.139.141/mailing:3000 don't work. The bitnami documentation says:

NOTE: Access to the server on port 3000 may be blocked for security reasons. In this case, you must first create an SSH tunnel between your local system and the server before you can access the application.

But I'cant make it work. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The port goes after the hostname, not at the end of the URL, it would be `http://44.197.139.141:3000/mailing`

Comment: Still don't work, I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, I just wandering if I have to configure a reverse proxy for apache. Thanks for the comment, it really help to understand the user of ports.

Comment: Did you open port 3000 in the AWS Lightsail security settings?

Comment: Mark B Thank you, that was the problem, I really appreciate your help, please reply the question to give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open port `3000` in the [Lightsail Instance Firewall](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail).